# Add gcc error text parsing to Kate?

Tags: parsing, gcc, message, kate

It seems an obvious improvement, in Kate, to jump directly to the error location given in a gcc error message. It would great if it can be made to work directly in Kate's terminal, but I would settle for a tool that can yank text off the x clipboard. Failing that, is there a way to write an add-on for Kate to do this?

Thanks.
Mike.

Answer (score 1):

from the terminal we can run something like this:

> $ kate source.cpp --line=45

you could write a script to parse gcc output and re-open kate to that line in the source.  If kate already has the source code open, it will simply emulate a jump to the line.

Answer (score 0):

There is ["Build" plugin](https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/applications/kate/kate-application-plugin-build.html) for Kate, which does also `stderr` parsing, and understand GCC error syntax.

So for example you can easily configure in Kate to build your project with make (and KDevelop is sharing this part of Kate source and plugin, although KDevelop has extra plugins for project management), and you will see in the Build plugin output parsed errors, clicking on them will direct you to the particular source file and line.

(but I was just looking around if it can even mark the error lines in the source visually, and actually there's nothing like it? From my limited understanding of the Kate plugin API I would be slightly afraid this is not trivial to add to current Build plugin, but I didn't dig into the Kate sources enough to fully understand its architecture and what are the true limits for plugin code).